# El misterioso mensaje "example"

Tags: php, laravel-5, swift-mailer

Veran, quiero mandarle a alguien un mensaje en Laravel.
Tengo esta función:

```
// Enviamos a un usuario inactivo un mensaje de activación.
public function mensajeActivar(User $usuario){
    Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new Mensajeria($usuario->id));

    return back()->with('message',['success',"Se ha enviado al usuario un mensaje que redirige al código de activación"]);
}
```

Este es el código de Mensajeria.php:

```
public $numero;

public function __construct($numero){
    $this->numero=$numero;
}

public function build(){
    return $this->view('correo.activacion');
}
```

Y este es el código de activacion.blade.php:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Active su cuenta en Bolsa Empleo</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <p>Se ha registrado con exito en el Aullido Vespertino.</p><br>
    <p>Pulse el siguiente enlace para activar su cuenta:</p><br>
    <a href='localhost/periodico/public/activar/{{$numero}}'>Activar su cuenta</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De donde proviene el misterioso texto "Example"?
¿Existe algún modo de quitarlo o sustituirlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ese que ves es el nombre del remitente del correo.

Tienes dos formas de cambiarlo.

- en `config/mail.php`

  establece la propiedad así:

  ```
  'from' => ['address' => 'tucorreo@tudominio.com', 'name' => 'El nombre que quieres que se vea']
  ```

  Este será el valor default para cada correo que envíes
- La otra es para ese único correo en particular, en tu código agrega:

  ```
  ->from('tucorreo@tudominio.com', 'El nombre que quieres que se vea')
  ```

Más información en la [documentación de Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail)

Comment: Pues ya esta reemplazado el mensaje.